# Как создать Repository в Oracle Designer и для чего он нужен?

Tags: oracle

Наверное я всем надоел со своим Oracle Designer, но все же такой вопрос. Повозившись несколько часов с настройками языка я смог запустить Designer, но в ответ получил сообщение:

> This user does not have installed Repository. Invoke the repository Administrator Utility.

Если можно, в двух словах как создать этот репозитарий (нормального урока не нашел) и для чего он нужен. И почему с Designerом так сложно работать?

Comment: @Yevgen Для перевода строки - нажать два раза Enter.

Comment: Это появляется прямо при старте? Какая база у вас? Express?

Comment: Появляется при старте после того как я выполняю подключение.
База Oracle 10g XE (Express Edition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Тут](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/152733/0/) что-то говорят об этом, но в конце утверждается, что этот Repository не поддерживается на XE. Вообще не пойму, почему он требует его от вас. Репозиторий - это репозиторий сервисов для SOA. Можете почитать про него, например, [тут](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/repository/overview/index.html)